# Flutter: How to set default value in a dropdown but i get some error

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

Easily I create a simple DropdownButton I don't facing any problem.But when I am trying to create a DropdownButton with set a fixed value then I getting an error. That says **Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value**. I have found a similar question on so and the solution says to initiate the strings with a value and I also doing this but I cannot figure out why it is not working here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Error Message**

```
    There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: all. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 849 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MyHomePage file:///home/user/Flutter/flutter_dynamic_dropdownLists/lib/main.dart:17:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new DropdownButton (package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart:849:15)
#3      _MyHomePageState.build (package:kdappdemo/main.dart:125:30)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4626:27)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4509:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4681:11)
```

**MyHomePage Class**

```
List statesList;
String _myState='all';

Future getShiftData() async {
    var res = await http.get("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5cc080ba8967d56779983203/1",});
    var resBody = await jsonDecode(res.body);

    setState(() {
      statesList = resBody['shift_info'];
    });
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    
    getShiftData();
    super.initState();
    
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('DropDown Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100, top: 100),
            child: Text(
              'Test',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      alignedDropdown: true,
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: _myState,
                        iconSize: 30,
                        icon: (null),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                        hint: Text('Select Shift'),
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _myState = newValue;
                            print(_myState);
                          });
                        },
                        items: statesList?.map((item) {
                              return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: new Text(item['shift']),
                                value: item['id'].toString(),
                              );
                            })?.toList() ??
                            [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is happening since your `_myState = 'all'` is not included in the `statesList` list. In other words, `statesList` does not have a value of `'all'`.

You can initialize `_myState` by the first value of the `statesList`:

```
Future getShiftData() async {
    var res = await http.get("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5cc080ba8967d56779983203/1",});
    var resBody = await jsonDecode(res.body);

    setState(() {
      statesList = resBody['shift_info'];
      _myState = statesList[0]['id'].toString();
    });
  }
```

Comment: when i apply your code in my codebase then i got fixed 0 index value but i don't want to this.I want to this _myState = 'all' is set by default when user click dropdown show all list data if someone is not select any data then set by default value in _myState = 'all'.